# Using rxjs .filter() on array of tags in Angular5

Tags: angular, filter, rxjs

**In Angular5, how can I use [rxjs .filter()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html) to filter an ObservableArray based on a tag (in an array of tags)?**

Here is the Product:

```
export class Product {
    id: string;    
    title: string;
    tags: string[];
}
```

And here is my ProductService:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductService {

    // get all products from the db
    getProductsAll (): Observable<Product[]> {

        // initiate the collection
        this.productsCollection = this.afs.collection( 'products', ref => ref.orderBy( "published, "desc" ) ); 

        // get the products from the initiated collection
        this.products = this.productsCollection.snapshotChanges()
        .map( actions => {
            return actions.map( a =>  {
                const id = a.payload.doc.id; 
                const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Product;
                return { id, ...data };
            })
        })

        // return the products as observable
        return this.products;
    }
```

So far, so good. Now the following is where I am **stuck**:

```
// get selected products filtered by their tag
getProductsByTag (): Observable<Product[]> {

    var filteredProducts = this.getProductsAll()
        // I know the next line is what causes the problem...
        .map( products => products.filter( product => product.tags == "shoes" ));

    // return the filtered products as observable
    return filteredProducts;    
}
```

As far as I can tell, the problem is that `tags` is an `array`, and the `.filter function` does not know how to handle that fact.

**How can I get it to filter using my array?**

Comment: So you want the filtering criterion to be whether `"shoes"` is *in* `product.tags`? In that case can't you just look up *"javascript find whether string is in array"* or similar?

Comment: Yes, I do want the filtering criterion to be whether `"shoes"` is in `product.tags`. I am thinking that this must be a common use-case and that there must be a best-practice solution to this problem? I have now worked out that I can supply a function to the `.filter()` function, and have gotten it to work using lodash `.find()` function as follows: `return _.find( product.tags, function(o) { return (o == "shoes"); });`. But it would still be helpful to know how this problem is usually solved in this scenario!

Comment: `product.tags.indexOf('shoes') > -1`? This is nothing to do with Angular or RxJS. Note that you're calling [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), **not** `Observable.filter`, hence my suggestion that you just look up standard JS methods for this.

Comment: So how do I change it to Observable.filter? My code is now: `var filteredProducts = this.getProductsAll()
.map( products => products.filter( product => 
return product.tags.indexOf( "shoes" ) > -1;
 }));`

Comment: Well, do you actually want it to be an observable filter? That would be filtering the *stream*, not the individual arrays in it. Otherwise, this is just a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/237104/3001761.

Comment: I don't know what I need here. Hence why I posted my whole, long example in hopes someone could kindly explain it.

Comment: In that case it would probably be helpful to **include what output you actually expect**, surely? Do you know what that is? Is what you get from your current `.map` *not* what you want? If it is, why do you think you need anything else? If not, what *do* you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your method to actually return `Observable<Product>` filtered by tag, you should first [flatMap](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/selectmany.md) your products then filter. You will still need to use `Array.includes` (or similar) on your tags as they are arrays:

```
getProductsByTag (tag: string): rx.Observable<Product> {
    return this.getProductsAll()
        .flatMap((products: Product[]) => rx.Observable.from(products))
        .filter((product: Product) => product.tags.includes(tag));  
}
```

You could also `flatMap` your tags, then use observable `filter` on tags, but this is less readable and more verbose:

```
getProductsByTag (tag: string): rx.Observable<Product> {
    return this.getProductsAll()
        .flatMap((products: Product[]) => rx.Observable.from(products))
        .flatMap((prod: Product) => rx.Observable.from(prod.tags), (product: Product, tag: string) => ({ product, tag }))
        .filter((data: any) => data.tag === tag)
        .map((data: any) => data.product)
}
```

Finally, if you really want the api to stay as `Observable<Products[]>` then you'd just do (which is just using `Array.filter` and `includes`):

```
getProductsByTag (tag: string): rx.Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.getProductsAll()
        .map((products: Product[]) => products.filter((product: Product) => product.tags.includes(tag)));  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`filter` is also a javascript array method, as well as observable method, so you don't need to do anything to the filteredProducts structure (see below, this runs as expected).
Just use `.includes()` to test for the required tag.
Ref [MDN Web Docs - Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const Observable = Rx.Observable;
const productsAll = Observable.of([ 
  {tags: ['shoes','coats']}, 
  {tags: ['hats','coats']} 
]);
productsAll.subscribe(console.log); // show productsAll emits once as an array

const filteredProducts = productsAll
  .map(products => products.filter( product => product.tags.includes('shoes') ));

filteredProducts.subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.js"></script>
```